# Display data from database wherein the date is within this week

Tags: php, database, date, if-statement, dayofweek

I have a code here that fetches the data in the database with a day within this week. For example: if the date today is 2015-08-27 and the date_paid column in the database has a value of 2015-08-26 and 2015-08-25, it will show the data that has either of those dates.
Here's the code that I've tried to fetch the date that is within this week:

```
// set current date
$date = date('Y-m-d');
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($date);
// find the year (ISO-8601 year number) and the current week
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);
// print week for the current date
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    // timestamp from ISO week date format
    $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
    //shows the date for 7days
    $week[$i] = date("Y-m-d", $ts) . "<br>";
}

if($week[1] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[1];
}

if($week[2] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[2];
}

if($week[3] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[3];
}

if($week[4] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[4];
}

if($week[5] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[5];
}

if($week[6] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[6];
}

if($week[7] == $date)
{
    $today = $week[7];
}

$transaction = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE date_paid = '$today'");
$counttrans = mysqli_num_rows($transaction);
```

This code suppose to fetch the data that has the day for that week. But it doesn't work. Anyone can fix this?

Comment: Could you please be more detailed when you say it doesn't work? What is the expected result and what is the actual result with your current code?

Comment: It doesn't fetch the data properly. The result of the count is always zero even if there's a value with that date within that week in the database.

Comment: The result should be more than 0 because in my database there are dates that is within this week like what I've said in my example.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the day of date_paid. Use MySQL function  'WEEKDAY'

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

here is an example.

```
select users.created_at as day_of_week, WEEKDAY(users.created_at)  
from users;
+---------------------+---------------------------+
| day_of_week         | WEEKDAY(users.created_at) |
+---------------------+---------------------------+
| 2015-08-26 05:22:29 |                         2 |
| 2015-08-04 14:14:32 |                         1 |
+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

we will select users created in day 1  by executing this query

```
select users.created_at as day_of_week  
from users  
where WEEKDAY(users.created_at) = '1';
+---------------------+
| day_of_week         |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-04 14:14:32 |
+---------------------+
```

in your case your query should look like this

```
"select transaction.date_paid as pay_day
 from transaction
 where WEEKDAY(transaction.date_paid ) =". $day;
```

Comment: Can you try it using the variables I used?

Comment: Inside the database, transaction is the table and date_paid is one of the columns inside the transaction table. I'm using a mySQL.

Comment: @JaeEun adapted query to your case see answer.

Comment: Do you have created_at column in your table?

Comment: I don't have created_at column in my table. But thanks by the way, I understand now how it works sorry I'm only a beginner in mysql. But I have another problem what if I want to fetch the data with a date for this year? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @JaeEun, You are welcome, I would be happy to help you or any other SO memeber.It is better if you ask a new question. If my answer did address your question, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.